# Excel - macro attached to form Control Button not activating

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have an odd issue with a single command button refusing to run the macro attached. I get the message "Cannot run the macro "". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

I have three buttons created by code on a new sheet and the macros assigned. The first two buttons work perfectly but the third does not. If I re-assign the same macro to the button (right click - assign macro) it works fine but this will not accomplish what I need.

All macros etc have been enabled. I hope someone can help, this is doing my head in!

```
    Sub AddButton()

    Dim ButtonName1, ButtonName2, ButtonName3 As String

    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(200, 5, 81, 36).Select
    ButtonName1 = Selection.Name
    Selection.OnAction = "CopyBack"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(ButtonName1).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Modify Scenario (Copy back)"

    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(285, 5, 81, 36).Select
    ButtonName2 = Selection.Name
    Selection.OnAction = "GotoPlanner"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(ButtonName2).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Return To Shift Planner"

    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(370, 5, 81, 36).Select
    ButtonName3 = Selection.Name
    Selection.OnAction = "DellCurrSheet"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(ButtonName3).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Delete This Scenario"

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the called code and tell us the name of the module the called code is in?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I have wasted anyones time on this but I have identified the typo which was causing the issue with the macro name assignment.